# Sencha CMD 4.0.0 - does not create corner image resources for older versions browsers under there old path

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I have upgraded to Sencha CMD 4.0.0, ever since that I see that on build the following resources are not being created under my custome theme resource directory:

```
GET .../n-theme/build/resources/images/panel-header/panel-header-default-top-bg.gif 404 Not Found (text/html)
GET .../n-theme/build/resources/images/grid/column-header-bg.gif 404 Not Found (text/html)
GET .../n-theme/build/resources/images/panel-header/panel-header-portlet-top-bg.gif 404 Not Found (text/html)
GET .../n-theme/build/resources/images/panel/panel-default-framed-sides.gif 404 Not Found (text/html)
GET .../n-theme/build/resources/images/panel/panel-default-framed-corners.gif 404 Not Found (text/html)
GET .../n-theme/build/resources/images/tip/tip-default-corners.gif 404 Not Found (text/html)
GET .../n-theme/build/resources/images/tip/tip-default-sides.gif 404 Not Found (text/html)
```

the resources are responsible for creating rounded corners for IE and other older browsers.

How can I tell the CMD to create theme again?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the [Image Slicing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command_slice) and [Theming](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/theming) guides in the Ext JS docs?

Once you understand those concepts, peek into any of the Ext JS 4.2.x themes (e.g. Neptune) to see how they are constructed with relation to your question.

Comment: I do not need any special cutting just the default panel coroners that used to work on Sencha 3.1.x. I don't understand why I change my configuration for it.